# Need help solving a filtering and sorting issue in my code

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-isotope

I'm having some issues with an isotope filter menu. I need it to load information based on a timestamp *and* allow for filtering. Unfortunately, something about my sortBy script is conflicting with the filter script.

Here is the js in question:

sortBy code:

```
$('.showcase').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.item',
    getSortData: {
        date: function ($elem) {
            return $elem.attr('data-timestamp');
        }
    },
    sortBy: 'date',
    sortAscending: true,
    masonry: {
        columnWidth: 1
    }
});
```

Filter menu code:

```
// filter container
var $container = $('.showcase');
$container.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.thumb'
});
var $optionSets = $('.filter'),
    $optionLinks = $optionSets.find('a');
$optionLinks.click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    // don't proceed if already selected
    if ($this.hasClass('selected')) {
        return false;
    }
    var $optionSet = $this.parents('.dropdown');
    $optionSet.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $this.addClass('selected');

    // make option object dynamically, i.e. { filter: '.my-filter-class' }
    var options = {},
    key = $optionSet.attr('data-option-key'),
        value = $this.attr('data-option-value');
    // parse 'false' as false boolean
    value = value === 'false' ? false : value;
    options[key] = value;
    if (key === 'layoutMode' && typeof changeLayoutMode === 'function') {
        // changes in layout modes need extra logic
        changeLayoutMode($this, options)
    } else {
        // otherwise, apply new options
        $container.isotope(options);
    }
    return false;
});
```

Here's a functioning jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3ngjL/2/

These two codes blocks work separately, but not together. If anyone can offer some insight, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out...

In the 'sortBy" chunk of code I declared the container for isotope:

```
$('.showcase').isotope({
```

Then named it again in the filter code:

```
var $container = $('.showcase');
    $container.isotope({
});
```

I fixed it by doing this:

```
var $container = $('.showcase');
  $container.isotope({
    itemSelector : '.thumb',
    getSortData : {
      date : function ( $elem ) {
        return $elem.attr('data-timestamp');
      }
    },
    sortBy : 'date',
    sortAscending : true
  });
```

Here's an updated fiddle with the working code: http://jsfiddle.net/3ngjL/3/